# psycopg2 connect to master in db cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Im struggling to find a way to always connect to master db in a cluster using psycopg2 im wondering is there a way to specify server type

As you would do in JDBC

```
jdbc:postgresql://{{dbclusteraddress}}/dbname?targetServerType=master&stringtype=unspecified
```

I cant find anything in the documentation that would give me something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just specific the hosts comma separated as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="ip1,ip2",
            port=port,
            database=db,
            user=user,
            password=pass,
            sslmode='require',
            target_session_attrs="read-write")
```